# How do i use -M flag to load a perl module using its relative path from command line?

Tags: perl, unix

I have following code:
demo.pm

```
#! user/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
package demo;
sub doit{
  print("Inside DoIt\n");
  my $a = shift();
  my $b = shift();
  print("$a\n");
}
```

The file demo.pm is located elsewhere and want to use relative path to fetch the module and run it

Using following from linux command throws error:

```
perl -M/sub1/sub2/demo.pm -e 'demo::doit('arg1')'
```

Error:

```
syntax error at -e line 0, near "use /sub1/"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Try using -I /path/to/directory/containing/lib

Comment: Tip: `#!` doesn't make sense in a module.

Comment: Tip: Modules must end with a true value. This is commonly achieved by adding `1;` at the end.

Comment: Tip: It looks a little better if you put the `use strict; use warnings;` after the `package` directive.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, will keep in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an absolute path and you want all scripts to find the module:

```
export PERL5LIB="${PERL5LIB:+"$PERL5LIB:"}/path/to/lib"  # In your login script.
script
```

If you have an absolute path and you want one execution of a script to find the module:

```
PERL5LIB="${PERL5LIB:+"$PERL5LIB:"}/path/to/lib" script
```

If you have a module that's installed in a directory relative to a script:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$RealBin/../lib";
```

---

In your specific case:

```
perl -Mlib=/sub1/sub2 -Mdemo -e'demo::doit("arg1")'
```

Avoid using `-I`. It doesn't include related arch dirs like `PERL5LIB` and lib.pm do, so modules with arch-specific components will fail to load.